# Zipping up a Web Root: Why didn't nice reduce CPU load?

Tags: linux, find, zip, nice

```
nice -n 19 find . -type f \( -iname "*.php" -o -iname "*.js" -o -iname "*.inc" \) \
  -exec zip live.zip '{}' \;
```

The above command runs on our live CentOS server as though the `nice` command was absent. After 60 seconds or so I can see that `zip` is on 'top' when using the `top` command. The server starts to fall over and I have to crash the command.

Comment: '*the Server starts to fall over*' - What do you mean by this? Secondly, `nice` is just to set a process' priority. If it is the *only* process consuming a lot of CPU time and resources, then it *will* eat up CPU time, until a process with higher priority comes along.

Comment: I see my mysql processes building up rapidly, then I get connection failures. Is it possible that mysqld has too low a priority?

Comment: I do not think increasing MySQL priority will help if it is already higher priority than your batch job.

Answer (score 3):

`nice` only sets a process' scheduling priority. It does not limit how much CPU time it consumes.

So: If a low priority process wants to consume a lot of CPU time/resources, then it *will* get them. *Until a process with higher priority comes along to hog CPU time.*

The point being: If the CPU doesn't have anything else to do, then why not provide all CPU time to the process that wants it, even if it doesn't have high priority?

If you want to limit CPU usage to a % of the maximum, then consider using something like [`cpulimit`](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/)

---

EDIT:

Other reasons why `zip` might be slowing things down horribly are:

1. Disk I/O: Which you can control with [`ionice`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice) on some distros (not sure if CentOS has it by default) - David Schmitt pointed this out in a comment below.
2. `zip` might allocate a lot of memory, and swap out other processes. Then when these processes wake up (say `mysqld` gets a query), they are sluggish. You might be able to do something about this by reducing [Swappiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness). But that is a system level parameter and you probably want to leave it untouched.

Comment: Arjun I understand that it would appear that once the zip grabs the CPU it doesn't let it go when a higher priority task comes along eg mysqld

Comment: 'letting go' of CPU is not up to the process. The kernel interrupts lower priority processes when one of higher priority comes along. You can read more about this here: http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html

Comment: Anyway, you should consider 'cpulimit' which I mentioned in my answer. It was written with exactly the same kind of issue in mind as yours, i.e. making sure batch jobs don't hog the CPU.

Comment: Also the process could create enough IO to hinder the rest of the services. There is an `ionice` too in recent distributions.

Comment: @DavidSchmitt - Yes. I have a feeling that another possible problem could be: `zip` swaps out a lot of other process' memory, and then on getting preempted, things get really slow until they are swapped back.

Comment: Would tar be any better? (and no ionice on my Centos)

Comment: @zzapper - `tar` by itself does not do any compression. It merely archives multiple files into one. So it should be faster/cheaper. `tar` when used with `gzip` seems to be a little 'faster', at the cost of producing a slightly bigger tarball, according to [this guy's simple test](http://birdhouse.org/blog/2010/03/08/zip-vs-tar-gzip/).

Comment: @ArjunShankar you are right in fact I don't need to do or rather shouldn't do the compression on the live server.

Comment: @zzapper - Yes `tar` will be a lot cheaper on resources if all you care about is archiving into a tarball, and not really compression. AFAIK, if you *want* to use compression, then `bzip2` has an option for doing it with low memory. Check out the 'MEMORY MANAGEMENT' section in `man bzip2` manual page.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments I infer that your server is low on memory and this is not actually an CPU or I/O or prioritization problem at all.

Try replacing the zipping with a streaming solution like tar. This should reduce the required memory considerably:

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.php" -o -iname "*.js" -o -iname "*.inc" \) -print0 \
    | xargs -0 tar cvzf live.tar.gz
```

Using `nice` on this command remains a choice to reduce the impact further. It has to be balanced with possible longer runtimes and the other resources (especially memory) that are used meanwhile.

Comment: BTW you are missing a -o in the above expression (didn't affect the speed much). I prefixed it with a 'nice' but don't know if that was necessary.

Comment: the `-o` was already missing on the Q, so I added it there to.

Comment: @DavidSchmitt "top" is saying that our mysqld is consistently running at 60% memory so I guess your suspicion that this is really a memory problem is likely correct!